# Weird characters, in place of the code in my Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, program-entry-point, bin

In my Pycharm IDE I had to implement the **main** in the python file under venv/bin/python in order to run my project but when I went to change the file it had a small picture of a page with a ? on it indicating it is an unknown file. I clicked on it and then a bunch of file options came up and so I picked python and then the weird character below showed up in the file. I would like to know how to fix this in the IDE because it saved it and is now affecting all my other projects.

```
             �-;     �-�     �-�     0      0                   T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   8�5     8�u     8�u     |�      |�             Q�td                                                  R�td   �-;     �-�     �-�     P      P             /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���?��&�
```

�����V�  �        ،Q�M P$@ ��F��`D % �!�   ���"    PB�   @�@"��SA��Q ���!��*�QP
 
� 8   � �@ ���! !

Comment: Why are you editing that file? That's the Python binary, you don't put your code there.

Comment: There is a `Run` menu in Pycharm that you can use to create and edit a Configuration that will allow you to run your project. You should never modify the python binary (as already said above)